# Does with and without async in DotNet's ExecuteNonQuery() affect MSSQL database performance?

Tags: sql-server, executenonquery

I'm looking at source code on DotNet framework that are using MS-SQL object, ExecuteNonQuery and ExecuteNonQueryAsync.

My understanding is the use of async and without async only affect application (Window Service) when it come to blocking and non-blocking call.

I'm getting a high CPU usage when a delete command was issued, in SQL Server Profiliing it showed CPU of 178 for a simple delete command.  The database index looks ok, when applying to SQL Query.

So, I wanna know is how much of SQL-Server performance improvement will be made if I switch the source code from `foo.ExecuteNonQuery()` to await `foo.ExecuteNonQueryAsync()`?   Does it make a difference in SQL Server or not?

Your knowledge and input will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> how much [...] performance improvement will be made if I switch [...] from foo.ExecuteNonQuery() to await foo.ExecuteNonQueryAsync()

None whatsoever. Your local client thread that is executing the query will not block with `ExecuteNonQueryAsync`, that's all. SQL Server will execute the query just the same.

What you should be doing is analyze why your query is taking so long by executing it in SQL Server Management Studio, including the Actual Execution Plan, and analyzing why it is that it's taking so long.

Perhaps your server is very busy, that's possible too. Or there is blocking going on due to concurrent transactions. A good tool to analyze this is Adam Machanic's tool [`sp_whoisactive`](https://www.brentozar.com/responder/log-sp_whoisactive-to-a-table/): *How to Log Activity Using sp_whoisactive in a Loop*

Comment: Adding to that: Yes, delete commands - particularly deleting multiple objects - can be expensive.

Comment: Thanks.  Confirmation on Async is all I need.  :-)  Yes, delete command is resources intensive.   Yes the server is very busy.  We have over 10 different databases on it and this one database is using realtime update per hour.  Now that Async is out of the way, I can now focus on profiling and tweaking them.

Comment: p.s. - brent ozar is great stuff.

Comment: @fletchsod You bet ;-)